# Why does setjmp/longjmp

Tags: c, setjmp

I want to use setjmp/longjmp to reuse some code inside the main function (NOTE: this is only an exercise and not something I ever seriously plan on doing in the real world).
The following code is what I've came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
jmp_buf jmp_body, jmp_ret;
    
void func(void)
{
    if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0)
        longjmp(jmp_body, 1);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    if (setjmp(jmp_body) == 1) {
        printf("Body %d\n", ++x);
        longjmp(jmp_ret, 1);
    }
    func();
    func();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

The way I expected this code to work is the following:

1. The `main()` function is going to remember where the 'body' part is and skip it using `if (setjmp(jmp_body) == 1)`.
2. The `func()` call is going to temporarily jump to the body using `longjmp(jmp_body)` after remembering where the body is supposed to return using `if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0)`
3. The body is going to execute and jump back to the `func()` call using `longjmp(jmp_ret, 1)`
4. The `func()` is just going to return to `main()` as expected.

Therefore, what I expected the code to print is the following:

```
Body 1
Body 2
Body 3
```

Instead, it loops forever continually executing the body which indicates to me the `func()` call isn't returning where it's supposed to and instead might be returning above itself executing itself over and over again.

In comparison, the following code prints just what I expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
jmp_buf jmp_body, jmp_ret;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    if (setjmp(jmp_body) == 1) {
        printf("Body %d\n", ++x);
        longjmp(jmp_ret, 1);
    }
    if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0)
        longjmp(jmp_body, 1);
    if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0)
        longjmp(jmp_body, 1);
    if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0)
        longjmp(jmp_body, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

What is it about putting `if (setjmp(jmp_ret) == 0) longjmp(jmp_body, 1)` inside a function call that makes the original approach invalid?

Comment: "temporarily jump" is an interesting expression.  There's nothing temporary  about it.  When you jump out of `func`, `jump_rec` is no longer valid.  So the subsequent attempt to long jump to it is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are misunderstanding what `longjmp` is and does.  You can only jump up the call stack, into a function which hasn't yet returned.  And when you do so, you implicitly return from the current function and all the ones in between; you can't then longjmp back to them.  It's not for jumping to random blocks of code throughout the program; it's instead for forcing several functions on the stack to return at once, like throwing an exception in languages which support that.

Comment: `longjmp()` does unwind the stack, everything that is in the unwinded part is no longer valid, you may inform yourself about stack unwinding and how `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` actually works. And please, use a consistent intention style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL/DR** - you can't jump back into a function you jumped out of.

> **7.13.2.1 The `longjmp` function**
> ...
> 2     The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of
> the `setjmp` macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding
> `jmp_buf` argument. If there has been no such invocation, or if the invocation was from
> another thread of execution, or ***if the function containing the invocation of the `setjmp`
> macro has terminated execution*<sup>248)</sup> *in the interim***, or if the invocation of the `setjmp`
> macro was within the scope of an identifier with variably modified type and execution has
> left that scope in the interim, ***the behavior is undefined***.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>248) For example, by executing a return statement or ***because another `longjmp` call has caused a
> transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.***</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

When you execute `longjmp(jump_body, 1);` in `func`, you *invalidate* `jump_ret`.

`longjmp` isn't bidirectional - it unwinds the stack as though any of the function calls between the `setjmp` and `longjmp` *never happened*.

Comment: Someone needs to tell that to [the Ruby developers](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5244)  Ruby totally ***abuses*** `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Good God.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to `longjmp` back down the stack from `main()` to `func()`. This is not defined. Since `longjmp` is itself a function, you most likely ended up `longjmp`ing into `func` with the return address being the `longjmp` call itself thus an infinite loop.